# Chernoff inequalities for the sum of Exponential RVs

Tags: probability, inequality

These two well-known [Chernoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bounds#Proof_2) bounds for the sum of RVs $X=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$ in mulitplicative form,

$\mathbf{P}(X \leq (1- \delta)\mathbf{E}X) \leq e^{-\frac{\delta^2 \mathbf{E}X}{2}}\\
\mathbf{P}(X \geq (1+ \delta)\mathbf{E}X) \leq \big(\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{(1+\delta)}} \big)^{\mu}
$

apply in the case when $X_k$ take values 0 and 1. I'm wondering if and how these results can extend in a more general case, e.g. when $X_k$ are exponentially distributed iid.

Comment: Yes, start from the same exponential inequality and optimize over $t$.

Comment: Thanks, could you give more details or explain this approach?

Comment: Show what you tried in this direction (the beginning merely copies the approach in the Bernoulli case explained on the WP page) and we will talk.

Comment: If  $ \mathbf{E} X_k = \frac{1}{\mu}$, then $\mathbf{E}X= \frac{n}{\mu}$ and MGF of X is $\varphi_{X}(t) = \bigg(\frac{\mu}{\mu-t} \bigg)^{n}$, so te upper bound using Markov inequality is $\mathbf{P}(X>(1+\delta)\mathbf{E}X) < \bigg(\frac{\mu}{\mu-t} \bigg)^{n}e^{-t(1+\delta)\mathbf{E}X}$, but I do not understand the whole optimization part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by the OP in a comment, Markov inequality yields
$$
P(X\gt(1+\delta)n/\mu)\leqslant \exp(-nI(t/\mu,\delta)),
$$
for every $t\gt0$, where
$$
I(s,\delta)=s(1+\delta)+\log(1-s).
$$
The derivative is $\partial_sI(s,\delta)=1+\delta-1/(1-s)$ hence the optimal choice is $s_\delta=\delta/(1+\delta)$, which yields $I(s_\delta,\delta)=\delta-\log(1+\delta)$, and finally,
$$
P(X\gt(1+\delta)n/\mu)\leqslant\left(\frac{1+\delta}{\mathrm e^\delta}\right)^n.
$$
To sum up, Markov (exponential) inequality yields a family of upper bounds, indexed by $t$ (or by $s$), and one chooses the value of $s$ (or of $t$) which minimizes this upper bound.

Comment: Thanks my only concern is that $\frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial s^2} = -\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}$, so $s_{\delta}$ is the maximum point when we want this point to be a minimum. What's wrong with this logic?

Comment: The upper bound is $\exp(-nI)$, with a minus sign, hence the most powerful upper bound is when $I$ is maximum. Let me suggest to draw the graph of $s\mapsto I(s,\delta)$.

Comment: great, thanks, I understand now.

Comment: That's nice. $ $