# Relation betweeen Hoeffding inequality and Chernoff bound?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

If I am correct, both Hoeffding inequality and Chernoff bound are about bounds on the probability of sample mean deviates from the true mean.

Besides that, I wonder how [Hoeffding inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_Case) and [Cernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) are related?

Is the conditioning Hoeffding inequality more restricted than Chernoff bound's?

Is the bound in Hoeffding inequality tighter than Chernoff bound's?

Is one the special case of the other? I.e. one can be derived from the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Both Hoeffding and Chernoff bounds are exponentially tight, which is better than Markov/Chebyshev, and both are special cases of Bernstein inequality (there is a Wikipedia article on it too

Comment: Thanks, @Alex! How is the relation between Bennett's inequality, and Bernstein inequality and other inequalities?

Comment: Have a look in Bennet's article, http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2282438, as far as I know Chernoff is the only one that exists readily in multiplicative form. All of them can be derived from Markov inequality, have a look here for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195064/chernoff-inequalities-for-the-sum-of-exponential-rvs

Comment: Thanks! I feel there are so many similar inequalities, and am so not sure which leads to which. Do you have some nice references for summarizing the results?

Comment: Yes, one of the (fairly recent) achievements include proof of Kolmogorov inequality. Try an article called 'Concentration inequalities' by Boucherone, Lugosi and Bousquet

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment (Please point out if I am wrong)

1) From [1], Chernoff established a bounding method in which the problem of bounding tail probabilities of sum of independent random
variables comes down to finding a upper bound for the moment generating function of the random variables.
For bounded random variables, Hoeffding provided such a upper bound.

2) From [2], Chernoff established the bounds for the domain of independent coin flips (1952), but it was Hoeffding who extended them to the general case (1963).

3) From [3], the Hoeffding inequality is a variant of the Chernoff bound, but often the bounds are collectively known as Chernoff-Hoeffding inequalities.

[1] Boucheron, Lugosi, and Bousquet, "Concentration Inequalities".

[2] https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sinclair/cs271/n14.pdf

[3] https://jeremykun.com/2013/04/15/probabilistic-bounds-a-primer/